# Merging Arrays in scala

Tags: scala

I have 3 Array

```
Array("1", "2", "3")

Array("orange", "Apple", "Grape")

Array("Milk", "juice", "cream")
```

on merging I need to output as

```
Array( Array("1", "orange", "Milk"), Array("2", "Apple", "juice"), Array("1", "Grape", "cream") )
```

Is this possible with Scala built in functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your arrays have the same length, this can be accomplished using `zip` and `map`

Define arrays

```
scala> Array("1", "2", "3")
res0: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> Array("orange", "Apple", "Grape")
res1: Array[String] = Array(orange, Apple, Grape)

scala> Array("Milk", "juice", "cream")
res2: Array[String] = Array(Milk, juice, cream)
```

`zip` them together in two steps. `zip` creates arrays of tuples

```
scala> res0 zip res1
res3: Array[(String, String)] = Array((1,orange), (2,Apple), (3,Grape))

scala> res3 zip res2
res4: Array[((String, String), String)] = Array(((1,orange),Milk), ((2,Apple),juice), ((3,Grape),cream))
```

`map` over the zipped result to transform the nested tuples to Arrays

```
scala> res4 map {case ((a,b),c) => Array(a,b,c) }
res5: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(1, orange, Milk), Array(2, Apple, juice), Array(3, Grape, cream))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also for

```
val a = Array("1", "2", "3")
val b = Array("orange", "Apple", "Grape")
val c = Array("Milk", "juice", "cream")
```

then

```
(a,b,c).zipped.map{ case(x,y,z) => Array(x,y,z) }
```

delivers

```
Array(Array(1, orange, Milk), Array(2, Apple, juice), Array(3, Grape, cream))
```

**Update**

Yet a different approach to those using zippers, simpler

```
Array(a,b,c).transpose
```

This allows for any number of input arrays, in contrast to zipper approachers which requires a priori knowledges of the number of input arrays for pattern-matching.